# Is there any good reason why ArrayList does not take Array as a constructor argument?

Tags: java, collections

It appears to me that it is very logical to give ArrayList an constructor which takes an array as an argument and creates an ArrayList that is equivalent to the array passed.

However at the moment we do not have such constructor. Instead we have to use Arrays.asList API to convert an array to ArrayList.

Why is it the case that conversion of Array to ArrayList is separated into Arrays API ? Is there any deeper thought into this design decision ?

Comment: Because they didn't put it in. Unless you get an author answering, which isn't likely, you're not going to get an authoritative answer either.

Comment: Non-authoritative answer (actually, total guess): because `ArrayList` wasn't generic originally?  I think it wouldn't have been feasible to implement this in the original pre-generic collections.  That doesn't explain why they didn't add it later, other than "just didn't think of it".

Comment: Whats funny is that `Arrays.asList(T... a)` doesnt actually return `java.util.ArrayList` it returns its own class that is also called `ArrayList` (`java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`). But if I was to guess as to why they didnt make the `ArrayList` class take an array was because it could cause confusion as to the mutable state of the array passed in the constructor.

Comment: I'd definitely agree with that: it's not clear whether it's copying or what.

Comment: The question has been asked before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302248/why-there-is-no-arraylistt-t-constructor), but may not have an answer you want.

Answer (score -3):

Arrays are object and their length are declared final. Arraylist resizable-array implementation of the List interface.